# Как убрать доступ к странице через URL на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть форма, которая в зависимости от результатов перенаправляет на одну из 4, созданных мною, страниц, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы кроме как перенаправления к ним не было никакого доступа, например через URL

Comment: Проверьте http_referer

Comment: В форме задайте wp_nonce. Проверяйте его.